Why is my "Run Selection" auto indenting indented lines in the terminal?
When I run a selection of code, the lines auto indent in the terminal. For example, if I wanted to import the function into the terminal session:
def test_func(var1):
    print('hello there')
    return

This is the behavior:

Each line has an additional tabs.
The behavior is also the same for a loop or any time I try to run a selection of indented code.
What settings do I need to adjust to prevent 'run selection' from auto indenting indented lines?

You're using Python 3.13, yeah? I believe this is a known issue, and there's probably an existing bug.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/79278325/11107541
